# Why is it so difficult to program a true random number generator?

Tags: random, prng

I don't understand why a PRNG is easier to program than a true RNG. Shouldn't a typical processor make short work of producing a truly random number?

Comment: I think this may better be answered on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Computers are deterministic machines, given the same input, code included, they will produce the same result.  To get true randomness you need to introduce something random from the real world, like the time or cosmic rays or something else that you can't predict.